# INPC and bind data during the run time windows phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I request data from server and after I got response I display them in grid and list boxes -TextBlock(like a table).Until here every thing is okay I finish the display function after that i must call new URL and desirelized the new JSON data to update the my grid table value for example:- my small application request login first after login success i request new URL that retrieve items in (JSON array) with sell price and buy price ==> here i draw my grid with this data like table as i told you before finally i need request new URL retrieve just the items that changed on the server with new prices ===> i dont know how to search in my grid textblock table to update the desired row, please help me (Please check my code below they told me there is an error with INPC and the for loop because when i request the second URL two times the new data not updated in my table ---> Please Advice)

---

This the my code with only the second URL call i don't know how to implement the third call and how to search into my table at the run time:-

```
public ObservableCollection<Data> DataReceivedCollection { get; set; }

private void FireRequest2()
{

    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://74.54.46.178/vertexweb10/webservice.svc/getallsymbols?AccountID=1122336675")) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
    request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
    {
        HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req2.EndGetResponse(ar))
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var outerRoot1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OuterRootObject1>(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(outerRoot1.d);
                    JToken jsonArray_Item = jsonArray.First;
                    while (jsonArray_Item != null)
                    {

                        string Name = jsonArray_Item.Value<string>("Name");
                        string Bid = jsonArray_Item.Value<string>("Bid");
                        string Ask = jsonArray_Item.Value<string>("Ask");
                        string ID = jsonArray_Item.Value<string>("ID");



                        DataReceivedCollection = new ObservableCollection<Data>();


                        DispatchInvoke(() =>
                        {
                            myList.ItemsSource = DataReceivedCollection;
                            // and to add data you do it like this:
                            DataReceivedCollection.Add(new Data() { symid = ID, textFirst = Name, textSecond = Bid, textThird = Ask });


                        }
);

                        //Be careful, you take the next from the current item, not from the JArray object.
                        jsonArray_Item = jsonArray_Item.Next;
                    }



                }
            }

        }

    }, request);
}
```

And here is my XAML:-

```
<Grid Background="#FFC9DC97" x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,140,12,0">
    <ListBox Name="myList" Background="#FFC9DC97">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition  Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ide" Text="{Binding symid}" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding textFirst}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FF1C69D8"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding textSecond}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding textThird}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

---

Here is the INotifyPropertyChanged Class

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _textFirst;
    public string textFirst
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _textFirst; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _textFirst)
            {
                _textFirst = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("textFirst");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _textSecond;
    public string textSecond
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _textSecond; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _textSecond)
            {
                _textSecond = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("textSecond");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _textThird;
    public string textThird
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _textThird; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _textThird)
            {
                _textThird = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("textThird");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _symid;
    public string symid
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _symid; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _symid)
            {
                _symid = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("symid");
            }
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Simplify your question, nobody's going to answer it as it is.

Comment: @Aybe, it is a "Russian Doll" question.  His last 5 questions are on the same application, and after each answer he gets 'stuck' on the next problem.  Each problem is different, but they arise in sequence as he progresses.  Read his history.  And this:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions

Comment: +1 he's learning the hard way :D

Answer (score 2):

In this fragment...

```
                    DataReceivedCollection = new ObservableCollection<Data>();


                    DispatchInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        myList.ItemsSource = DataReceivedCollection;
                        // and to add data you do it like this:
                        DataReceivedCollection.Add(new Data() { symid = ID, textFirst = Name, textSecond = Bid, textThird = Ask });


                    }
```

You are destroying all previous data by reinitializing the DataReceivedCollection.  So it is empty.  Then in the dispatcher thread you are binding to it, and then adding to it.  And you are repeating the whole thing all over on each pass or the while `(jsonArray_Item != null)` loop.

The observable collection and binding should be set **once**, at initialization time.  Not each and every time you pass through a loop.  If you want to set the collection to empty, use `DataReceivedCollection.Clear();

Move these lines to one-time initialization...

```
DataReceivedCollection = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
myList.ItemsSource = DataReceivedCollection;
```

Moreover, since you are dispatching the 'Add' (which is correct), you are inviting a closure problem, i.e., variables may be out of scope before the dispatcher thread executes.

Move these lines into the dispatcher thread...

```
                string Name = jsonArray_Item.Value<string>("Name");
                string Bid = jsonArray_Item.Value<string>("Bid");
                string Ask = jsonArray_Item.Value<string>("Ask");
                string ID = jsonArray_Item.Value<string>("ID");
```

Your implementation of INPC looks good.  At this point it's just your logic flow that needs adjustment.

Comment: Garry I`m in WPF room chat are you there

Comment: there now, see you there